# AJAX Обновление нескольких div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код

```
<div id="ddd">id ddd не изменился</div>
<div id="fff">id fff не изменился</div>

            <script>
                function AjaxGetData (url, statbox, type, data){
                    ajax({
                        url:url,
                        statbox:statbox,
                        method:"POST",
                        data:
                        {
                            type: type,
                            data: data,
                        },

                        success:function(data){
                            document.getElementById(statbox).innerHTML=data;
                        }
                    });
                };

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    AjaxGetData ("AjaxGetData.php", "ddd", "ddd", 1);
                    AjaxGetData ("AjaxGetData.php", "fff", "fff", 1);
                });     
            </script>
```

Ну и php (AjaxGetData.php)

```
if($_POST){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

В `<div id="fff">` всё нормально отображается, а в `<div id="ddd">` нет.

Подскажите, где что я упустил.

Comment: А почему бы не делать один запрос возвращать данные в JSON  и просто не распределяять полученные данные по вашим блокам?

Comment: Это просто пример. На самом деле, функций будет больше и все они будут разные, а не только AjaxGetData.php. И не всегда они будут совпадать на разных страницах.   Мне не ясно, почему не работает именно так.

Comment: на локальном сервере у меня ваш код работает как нужно

Comment: это странно, у меня не хочет на трех машинах (две - локальные сервера)

Comment: Какой браузер и ос? Если не секрет? https://jsfiddle.net/jzw69zdt/ Ваш код с 1й и 2й версией jquery работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте синхронные запросы с проверкой статуса ответа

```
<script>
                function AjaxGetData (url, statbox, type, data){
                    var res = $.ajax({
                        url:url,
                        statbox:statbox,
                        method:"POST",
                        async: false,
                        data:
                        {
                            type: type,
                            data: data,
                        },

                        success:function(data){
                            document.getElementById(statbox).innerHTML=data;                            
                        }
                    }).status;

                    return res;
                };

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var status = AjaxGetData ("res.php", "ddd", "ddd", 1);
                    if (status == 200) AjaxGetData ("res.php", "fff", "fff", 1);
                });     
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/ajax.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data.succes == 0){
           document.getElementById('stat1').innerHTML=data.stat1;
           document.getElementById('stat2').innerHTML=data.stat2;

        }
    }
});
```

ajax.php

```
$json_output = array('succes'=>1, 'stat1'=>'53', 'stat3'=>'10');
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

Comment: Это хорошо, если url всегда один.

Comment: а ну тогда надо ставить цикл и в нем перебирать все ссылки.

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему не работает описанный мною код. Можете сказать, что не так?

Comment: ну правильно не будет работать, попробуйте ради интереса поставить отсрочку после запроса к первому... setTimeout(function(){  AjaxGetData ("AjaxGetData.php", "fff", "fff", 1); }, 10000);

Comment: пробовал, с паузой работает. только трудно угадать, какую ставить) на костыль больше похоже...  c alert'ом между вызовами хорошо работает))

Comment: сделать в первой setTimeout(function(){ AjaxGetData ("AjaxGetData.php", "fff", "fff", 1); setTimeout(function(){ AjaxGetData ("AjaxGetData2.php", "fff", "fff", 1); }, 10000); }, 10000);